# Battlefield 3 Server list shows no pings

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

The Battlelog Server Browser shows no ping values for servers.
http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/servers/

I Google'd the problem - there are quite a number of reports on the issue, but none of the tips worked:

- Firewall
- Browser in Admin mode
- Another browser
  Using Firefox 22, also tried Chrome 28 and IE9
- New browser tab or new window
- F5
- Refreshing page N times

Does anyone successfully resolved this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the browser plugin was outdated. The BL noticed about this only when I clicked on Join Server, then I upgraded the browser plugin, and the ping numbers appeared after a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Holding <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> solves it for me.